# nonClickable buttons after loading same FLA 2nd time

Tags: actionscript-3

Basically Im trying to make a FLA where if i click a button and close the FLA, next time I load the same FLA, the buttons that have been clicked before , now have an alpha of 0.5 and are nonClickable.

Currently i have only the logic for creating the buttons and saving the data:

```
    private var savedData:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("sharedStorage10");
    private var buttonInfoArr:Array = [];

    public function Main()
    {

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var myImage_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

            myImage_mc.graphics.beginFill( 0xFFFFFF * Math.random() );
            myImage_mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
            myImage_mc.graphics.endFill();

            myImage_mc.x = 50 + i * (myImage_mc.width + 10);
            myImage_mc.y = 100;
            myImage_mc.name = "myImage_mc" + i
            this.addChild(myImage_mc);

            myImage_mc.mouseEnabled = true;
            myImage_mc.buttonMode = true;
            myImage_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }
    }

    private function onClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var thisButton:MovieClip = ev.currentTarget as MovieClip

            trace(thisButton.name)

            thisButton.alpha = 0.5
            thisButton.buttonMode = false;
            thisButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

            buttonInfoArr.push( thisButton.name );
            savedData.data.myArray = buttonInfoArr;
    }
```

But i dont know how to load/use the data and make the buttons (that have been clicked before) start with an **alpha** of 0.5 and without an **EventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)**

PS:Could it be done without the use of **Dictionary**, cause i haven`t grasp my mind over it yet.

_*EDIT***__**

---

to represent my problem in a more detailed  way:

So im creating a game in which I collect objects that represent money.After I die in the game i get into the **Shop** Class in which i can buy different items depending on the money i have.
So lets say that after dying i have enough money to get **item1** and **item2**. So i Click on ***button1*** (representing item1) and  ***button2*** (representing item2) (when clicked their alpha gets to 0.5) and start the game again.Ok so now i have **1 life more** and **i get more money**.But suddenly out of nowhere i feel something strange deep in me, something that i have never felt before -> HUNGER,

I shut down the PC (cause I love Earth )and run as fast as possible to the nearest shop.

lets say item1 is : +1life         and item2 is : get more money from objects

After I had satisfied my primal needs I feel the strong urge to play that awesome game of mine again. But when i start the game I start to see some strange things: It seems that I havent got **one life more**  and **neither do i get more money** and just to be sure that Im not hallucinating  (or that i didnt rememer the lifes i had last time) I die on purpose so the Shop menu shows. So now what I see is  making me sad -> **button1** and **button2** are active  and have an alpha of 1( and that means that the game thinks that they were never bought/clicked, that i have never played this game before in my life) 
So i go crazy (cause  all that play before was for nothing and i have to start all over again).

After i calm down, I decide to change my life. 1st BIG change is adding some code into the game. To be more specific: a method that will save the items that i bougth, so when i close the game and start again the things i see will bring joy to my life  - >: I still have the items that i bougth last time.

So long story short:
how do i make that when i click a button (it changes its alpha to 0.5)and close the FLA ,
whenever i open the same FLA, the button that i clicked before will be shown as clicked now(it alpha will be 0.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is normal. All variables are stored in RAM, which is temporary memory. Your button states are variables, too. Whenever any program closes, everything it has in RAM is deleted, thus the variables are cleared. This is true of all programs, in all programming languages. There are absolutely no exceptions.

Quite simply, you need to create a file that can store all this data long-term, on the hard drive (which is "permanent" memory).

If you're creating a game for the internet, you're going to need to store this data using [SharedObjects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d80.html) (a.k.a. cookies).

If you're creating a game to be installed on the computer or mobile, you'll want to store data in a file. I recommend [XML files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html), as they're the easiest to work with by far.

I am not going into either here, because those are lectures, not SO answers. See the above links to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what exactly you're trying to do. But here is my simply approach would be that way.

```
// this is basically saved your latest clip we will control this if user click this button then we will be blocked

private var lastClickedButton:MovieClip;

private function onClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
        var thisButton:MovieClip = ev.currentTarget as MovieClip

            trace(thisButton.name)

            thisButton.alpha = 0.5
            thisButton.buttonMode = false;
            thisButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

            buttonInfoArr.push( thisButton.name );
            savedData.data.myArray = buttonInfoArr;

            // set the lastclicked button
            lastClickedButton = thisButton;

            // save this savedData sharedObject
            savedData.data.lastClickedItem = lastClickedButton;
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop)
{
    if(savedData.data.lastClickedItem)
    {
        // do something here.
        lastClickedButton.alpha = 0.5;
        lastClickedButton.mouseEnabled=false;
        // clear your sharedobject
        savedData.flush();
    } 
}
```

I hope this will help you. good luck...

Comment: well i dont get it. Why would i need an Enter_Frame function when i just need to see if the button was clicked at the start of the game(this means that when the Main Class is loaded)